# Putting a list(user input) as a value in HashMap in java

Tags: java, list, hashmap

The following code get score from the user and stores it in scores list. How can i store this list in a HashMap, where each list should hold only 2 values.

```
final int TOTAL_NO_OF_MATCHES = 2;
final int TOTAL_NO_OF_PLAYERS = 2;
List<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<>(); 
LinkedHashMap<String, List<Integer>> batsmanScores = new LinkedHashMap<>();
// LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> match2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
// LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> match3 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
// LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> match4 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
// LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> match5 = new LinkedHashMap<>();

void storingScores()
{
    String batsmanName;
    for(int player = 1; player <= TOTAL_NO_OF_PLAYERS; player++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the Batsman"+player+"'s data: ");
        System.out.println("Enter the batsman's name: ");
        batsmanName = scan.nextLine();
        for(int match = 1; match <= TOTAL_NO_OF_MATCHES; match++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the score of Match"+match+": ");
            int score = scan.nextInt();           
            scores.add(score);
        }
        scan.nextLine();
        batsmanScores.put(batsmanName, scores);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what is the problem/what is not working?

Comment: I get score(int) input from the user and stores it in scores(list) and then, i put this scores(list) in a Hashmap. What i want is, when user enter the scores of the second player(i put it in the scores list), it should only store those scores, should not include the score of first player's score too. How do i achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to re-initialize the `scores` list each time in the loop.

```
for(int player = 1; player <= TOTAL_NO_OF_PLAYERS; player++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter the Batsman"+player+"'s data: ");
    System.out.println("Enter the batsman's name: ");
    batsmanName = scan.nextLine();
    scores = new ArrayList<>(); //create new scores list

    for(int match = 1; match <= TOTAL_NO_OF_MATCHES; match++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the score of Match"+match+": ");
        int score = scan.nextInt();           
        scores.add(score);
    }
    scan.nextLine();
    batsmanScores.put(batsmanName, scores);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what i was looking for. But, is there any other way to do this in the already existed scores list?

Comment: No, you have to create a new instance. Otherwise, it will keep adding to the same as it did